# duplicated Smoke emmiters

Tags: physics, smoke-simulation

I am trying to do various smoke emitters on this secene, so i did one and duplicated it, but when i render they both emit the same, even if i have changed the size and the position of one of the emmiters, i tried to clean caché, but one of them keep rendering the same than the other.

The bottom one seems to work well, but the top one, nope.

I have to redo all the presets of one of the emmiters? or there is a way to do two differents emissions?[image]

Comment: you have to change any property of the domain if you want to change a property of an emitter to take effect.

Comment: i have tried, but nothing, must be one particular property for it.

Comment: do you use different cache names?

Comment: OMG was that! i'm so stupid, THANKS!

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad that fixed it :-)